# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 while installing sumo-planetsumo

Tags: xcode, makefile, sumo, plexe-veins, plexe

I am trying to install sumo-planetsumo in order to run my scenarios on my macOS High Sierra, however after make -f Makefile.cvs and ./configure "make" produces the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[3]: *** [netgenerate] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I do have other sumo versions installed on my pc and have been able to change paths in order to use them. I wonder if this has anything to do with the older versions, or xcode itself. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this issue, at least on my system. I solved this problem by simply specifying the architecture during configuration. Like so:
`./configure CC="gcc -arch x86_64"`
You can specify for multiple architectures, for example, like so:
`./configure CC="gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64" \`
`CXX="g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64" \`
`CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E"`
I am still surprised because I expected auto-reconfigure to sort that out automatically and hence didn't think much of this specification until the build completed. Good luck.